# Tab collapse in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

In my code i have bootstrap 4 Tab .I want first all the tab-content will be hide  when i click tab li then the tab-contents will be shown.
For that i've removed the active class from tab-pane div so now at first contents are not showing and when i click on the tab li it is showing then but after i click on that li again it does not closing .

I want when again i click the tab li button the tab contents should be closed again.

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="home" role="tabpanel">A</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">B</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">C</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">D</div>
</div>
```

Just want when click the menu it will show the content and when click again the menu it should close.

Help me

Comment: what version for used ? Beta or Alpha

Comment: I'm using bootstrap4 alpha

Comment: On second click what should happen? What do you mean by `it does not closing`?

Comment: i want all to be hideen,when i click the li tabs it should open the content .and when i click the li again it should close the tab content .same goes for 1st,2nd,3rd,4th menu items..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

Add this extra code to remove the active class on click again.

```
$(document).on('click','.nav-link.active', function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').removeClass('active');
})
```

```js
$(document).on('click','.nav-link.active', function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
  //alert(href);
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').removeClass('active');
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>






<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="home" role="tabpanel">A</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">B</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">C</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much i was looking for that answer

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: There is another problem.
whn you click the menu buttons more than 2times it not working

Comment: It should be 

$('.tab-pane[id="'+ href +'"]').toggleClass('active');

Comment: See the updated answer. add this line `$(this).removeClass('active')`

Comment: @Bhuwan this line `$(this).removeClass('active')` is not working in my page. If I removed then it hides the content when clicking the active tab but got same previous errors. Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Now its working 
use following **Bootstrap CDN**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>






<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="home" role="tabpanel">A</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">B</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">C</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You pasted the same code to me which i've asked for to change..And it is also not working

Comment: @Tanmay please check your `CDN`

Comment: i want all to be hidden,when i click the li tabs it should open the content .and when i click the li again it should close the tab content .same goes for 1st,2nd,3rd,4th menu items.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following Bootstrap CDN to your code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```